# Adding concatenation of unique values as groupby output in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Imagine you have a dataframe **df** as follows:

```
Id   Side Volume
2    a    40
2    b    30
1    a    20
2    b    10
```

You want the following output

```
Id  Side sum
1   a    20
1   all  20
2   a    40
2   b    40
2   all  80
all a    60
all b    40
all all  100
```

Which would be a `df.groupby(['Id','Side'].C.sum().reset_index()` AND the sum values for all side and all id's (`df.Volume.sum()`, `df[df.Side == 'a'].Volume.sum()`, `df[df.Side == 'b'].Volume.sum()`, etc...)?

Is there a way to do this without calculating it outside and then merging both results?

Comment: you can either do a series of groupby and re-merge, if you don't want to do that you can do a series of column and row assignment using `.loc` but will be difficult. why can't you use merge or concat ?

Comment: @Datanovice It's not that I can't, I am looking for a cleaner option. If the number of columns is 10+, it starts to become very long for something that could maybe just be an option somewhere, I just haven't been able to find one.

Comment: by variables do you mean columns or obersveations in a given column ?

Comment: I meant columns